# Jquery Ui Draggable updating diffrent css attributes

Tags: php, jquery

Hello friends i want to know if i can use jquery draggable plugin to update margin-left and margin-top property by default it updates left and top properties of css on drag event.
please help

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can

```
 $( "#box" ).draggable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {

      $( "#box" ).css('margin-top',$("#box").offset().top).css('top',0);
      $( "#box" ).css('margin-left',$("#box").offset().left).css('left',0);

}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CnDfF/3/